# Can you render Bézier curves without giving their geometry thickness?

Tags: shaders, bezier-curves, lines

**Is there a simple way to render Bézier curves in either Eevee or Cycles, while their bevel property is zero (so that their geometry has no thickness)?**

I suspect there might be because shaders can also modify geometry somewhat (e. g. Displacement nodes).

What I'm looking to achieve are simple, solid colored lines of variable thickness, similar to what you might get from Greasepencil Strokes or Freestyle.
(I'm working on a technical sketch, and not having to deal with any bevel in the geometry would be much easier. A workaround would be to add the bevel with a geometry node modifier shared by all lines, so that it can still be adjusted globally.)

Comment: If there's no geometry then there is nothing to render, even with Grease Pencil. Geometry nodes can be used bevel all curves

Comment: As @DuarteFarrajotaRamos says and you already suspected, _Geometry Nodes_ might be a good way to do this. Even if all curves are spearate objects, you can simply put them all in one collection which you reference with a _Collection Info_ node in the _Geometry Nodes_ setup. Plug this into a _Curve to Mesh_ node and use a _Curve Circle_ or whatever you want as _Profile Curve_. Changing the radius will then be affecting all curves in the collection. You could even create different collections e.g. one for thin lines and one for thicker lines and combine them.

Comment: you can also simply do it by changing the curve data associated to the bevel object that is needed for rendering. When editing, no curve in it, so you can edit without being annoyed by that shape. When rendering add the wanted shape in it.